# How to print part of .tex code to pdf

Tags: graphics, diagrams

My friends send me this `.tex` code, but it is only part of the code. I need your help to edit this code into a full document, because when I insert this code to TeXworks it does not compile into a pdf file.

This is the part of code which I need to be edited into a full document:

```
digraph {
A [peripheries = 2];
B [peripheries = 2];

A->B [label = "a"];
S->A [label = "a"];

A->A [label = "b"];
S->S [label = "b"];

A->S [label = "c"];
S->B [label = "c"];

}
```

Console output:

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (Web2C 2010)  restricted
>   \write18 enabled. entering extended mode (./untitled-1.tex LaTeX2e
>   <2009/09/24> Loading CZ hyphenation patterns: Pavel Sevecek, v3, 1995
>   Loading SK hyphenation patterns: Jana Chlebikova, 1992
>
> ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...
>
> ```
>                                                l.1 d
>  igraph { ?
> ```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: its graph of automation

Comment: Please, post your preamble. Are you trying to compile only this code?

Comment: Try `dot2tex` maybe: http://www.fauskes.net/code/dot2tex/

Answer (score 1):

To compile that code you would need a `dot` language interpreter (i.e. `graphviz` or equivalent) which through a package (or otherwise) could spit out `TiKz` (or equivalent) code.  I don't have `graphviz` installed, but I do have `Gephi` installed.  I made a `.dot` file that contains your code and had `Gephi` do the layout and then exported to `TiKz`.  The result could be improved (label adjustments etc.) if I knew any `TiKz` but I don't so unfortunately I can't help you there.  Below is the output and generated `.tex` file.

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz, tkz-graph}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{COLOR0}{rgb}{0.6,0.6,0.6}
\definecolor{COLOR1}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0.8159795,0) [circle, line width=1, fill=COLOR0,  inner sep=0pt, minimum size = 5pt, label={[label distance=0] 315:A}] (1) {};
\node at (-1.6908659,4.5319248) [circle, line width=1, fill=COLOR0,  inner sep=0pt, minimum size = 5pt, label={[label distance=0] 315:B}] (2) {};
\node at (0.8748864,5.7434276) [circle, line width=1, fill=COLOR0,  inner sep=0pt, minimum size = 5pt, label={[label distance=0] 315:S}] (3) {};
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style = {->,shorten >=1pt,>=stealth, bend right=10}}
\tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style = {->, shorten >=1pt, >=stealth, bend right=10, line width=0.5, color=COLOR0}}
\Loop[dist=1cm,dir=EA,style={->,shorten >=1pt,>=stealth,line width=0.5}, color=COLOR1, label=b](1)
\Edge [label=a](1)(2)
\Edge [label=c](1)(3)
\Edge [label=a](3)(1)
\Edge [label=c](3)(2)
\Loop[dist=1cm,dir=EA,style={->,shorten >=1pt,>=stealth,line width=0.5}, color=COLOR1, label=b](3)
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Googling digraph latex produced this:

You need `graphviz.sty` (available [here](http://mark.aufflick.com/blog/2007/03/25/embedding-graphviz-in-latex-documents)) and you need the following in your document preamble:

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphviz}
```

Comment: Where would one find your graphviz.sty? This answer seems a little useless without it.

Comment: The information in the answer, including a description of `graphviz.sty`, is from [here](http://mark.aufflick.com/blog/2007/03/25/embedding-graphviz-in-latex-documents).

Comment: The fact that the OP tried to `latex` the code snippet as is suggests s/he does not know what a full latex document is.  (As the error shows, the first line of the supposed latex file was `digraph`).  A real answer should probably provide a full and compilable latex file.